# Retrieve Systems Manager Explorer OpsData Using CLI or SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I'm trying to retrieve below details using **java SDK or CLI**.

[image: OpsData for COMPLIANT items]

I found below CLI commands for that but in **sample responses** I don't see an appropriate CLI command for that.

1. [describe-ops-items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/describe-ops-items.html)
2. [get-ops-item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-ops-item.html)
3. [get-ops-metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-ops-metadata.html)
4. [get-ops-summary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-ops-summary.html)
5. [list-ops-item-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/list-ops-item-events.html)
6. [list-ops-item-related-items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/list-ops-item-related-items.html)
7. [list-ops-metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/list-ops-metadata.html)

Trying out each CLI is not an option since this is very sensitive data and cannot request permission for all CLI methods..

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen that there is a method **list-compliance-summaries** ?

From the [official docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/list-compliance-summaries.html):

> Returns a summary count of compliant and non-compliant resources for a compliance type. For example, this call can return State Manager associations, patches, or custom compliance types according to the filter criteria that you specify.

Comment: I hate to resurrect a dead thing... but this doesn't work from the Global OpsData view where multiple account data is aggregated. I don't know if the OP is looking for Org data, or not (though I am), and this CLI command doesn't support the `--sync-data` flag that some of the *-ops-* calls do.